# ElementName Binding In ToolTip

Tags: xaml, silverlight, data-binding, tooltip

I have a Silverlight application.

I need to add a Tooltip to a textblock that will display information about an other element (a GridView)

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Test"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="12"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            Foreground="DimGray"
            Visibility="Visible">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Items.Count,
                ElementName=SearchResultsPresenter,
                StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding
                Source={StaticResource PublicResourceStrings},
                Path=ResourceStrings.SEARCH_RESULTS_DISPLAYED}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItems.Count,
                ElementName=SearchResultsPresenter,
                StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding
                Source={StaticResource PublicResourceStrings},
                Path=ResourceStrings.SEARCH_RESULTS_SELECTED}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </ToolTip>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

But the binding with an elementName doesn't work. Items.Count and SelectedItems.Count display "0"...

I found [this](https://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/elementname-binding-in-tooltips-borrowing-a-namescope/) but it seems a bit complicated. Is there a simple solution to do what I need ?

Comment: I assume SearchResultsPresenter is your GridView, if it's you're GridView I think you'd want Children.Count (but that would cause [a memory leak](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls)) you'd want to bind to the binding path that populates the gridview to get your count. Might share more code.

Comment: Thx. Yes, SearchResultsPresenter is my GridView (a RadGridView in fact... from Telerik) with the property ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}". I can use this Binding instead of Items.Count in my ToolTip, but how can I display SelectedItems.Count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BindableObjectReference x:Key="BindableGridView"
            Object="{Binding ElementName=SearchResultsPresenter}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <RadGridView x:Name="SearchResultsPresenter"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
              <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding
                    Path=Object.Items.Count,
                    Source={StaticResource BindableGridView}}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding
                    Path=Object.SelectedItems.Count,
                    Source={StaticResource BindableGridView}}"/>
              </TextBlock>
            <ToolTip>
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

and code:

```
public class BindableObjectReference : DependencyObject
{
    public object Object
    {
        get { return GetValue( ObjectProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ObjectProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Object", typeof( object ),
        typeof( BindableObjectReference ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );
}
```

Comment: I can't help it. I'm a Silverlight nerd ;)

Comment: That's a phrase you don't hear too often these days lol, but aye, me too.

Comment: It's a pity, Silverlight is a good framework. And after working with Silverlight for a few years now I think I figured out "how to do stuff properly in Silverlight" in a way that is well supported by the framework and maybe counts as "as-the-creators-intended". Alas! I'm doing more and more HTML 5 now, complete with AngularJS and TypeScript... and I'm a beginner once more.

Comment: Haha I'm right there with you on having to delve into the HTML5 stuff, we're still developing on and supporting a very large SL5 solution while migrating towards it. Which is a shame because honestly I appreciate XAML much more than I do HTML5, not to mention dev'ing for cross-browser/cross-device can be a real pain in the @$$. So amen.